# C#: How to search for a specific character in a string by using IndexOf?

Tags: c#

I want to use IndexOf to search for a specific character in the string, but not sure how to do it.

For example, for 18:30:00, I want to collect 18 and 30, and ignore the rest. I used the LastIndexOf, but it is not working correctly.

Here is the code: (assume input is 18:30:00)

```
set
        {
            int first = value.IndexOf(':');
            string hour = value.Substring(0, first); //first = 18
            int second = value.LastIndexOf(':');
            string mins = value.Substring(0, second; // second should be 30, but it keeps give me 0
        }
```

Comment: I suspect your value isn't what you think it is. Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. I'd also suggest just parsing this as a `TimeSpan` or a `DateTime` (although there's no date part - in Noda Time you'd parse it as a `LocalTime`).

Comment: Use `string.split` instead, and split on the `:`, you'll get an array with 3 indicies, the first will be hours, then minutes and seconds. And according to your input string, seconds should be 00, its minutes that should be 30.

Comment: Your second Substring call is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not let the framework do it for you?

```
var time = TimeSpan.Parse("18:30:00");
//time.Hours = 18
//time.Minutes = 30
```

Parsing your string as a `TimeSpan` gives you exactly what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

In general, to parse Date/Time you should use DateTime.Parse() method.
For your particular case, please take into account *value* remains the same after you do .Substring(), so your second call will start from the same position.

Another way to solve your task can be to use String.Split

```
        var line = "18:30:00";
        var items = line.Split(new[] {":"}, StringSplitOptions.None).Select(strValue => Convert.ToInt32(strValue)).ToArray();
        var hour = items[0];
        var minute = items[1];
        var second = items[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

OP asked for IndexOf() solution to get the desired results.  This will give the second occurrence of ":"

```
int second = value.IndexOf(':', value.IndexOf(':') + 1);
```

Comment: Since there are only two `:` in the string, `LastIndexOf` should return the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Since everyone's answer is related to TimeSpan or Split, I will post mine. 
I used IndexOf, so it will search for any character (numbers & text etc.) instead of time only.

So we are looking for hour values and mins value in a string looks like (00:00:00). I will use 18:30:00 as an example value.

```
int first = value.IndexOf(':'); //18:30:00
int hour = Convert.ToInt32(value.Substring(0, first)); // get the value of hour = 18
string minushr = value.Substring(first + 1); // get the value of the rest (30:00)
int last = minushr.IndexOf(':'); //30:00
string min = minushr.Substring(0, last); //Get the value of mins = 30
```